# Alternative to CSV Serde in hive 0.14

Tags: csv, hive

Is there any alternative to csv serde in Hive 0.14 as the csv serde will convert all the values in string, but i have a hive table which has the columns in different data type like int, float and string .?

Answer (score 0):

use MultiDelimitSerDe
it can be also used in most cases alternative to csv serde.
if you can give more use case , then we can help you better.